# Javascript Singleton communication definition required

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, javascript-objects

I made a object to keep my functions became singleton, using that, i made sample methods to call and communicate each other.. but i don't get any appropriate results..

any one correct me, the singleton the way i defined here...

my sample codes:

```
var obj = window[obj] || {}; //singleton

obj.nameIt = function(name){

    this.name = name;

    this.getName = function(){
        return this.name;
    }

}

obj.sayIt = function(name){

    this.name = name; var that = this;

    this.sayHello = function(){
        console.log("say" + this.name);
        that.getName();//how to get result from nameIt?
    }

}

var x = obj.nameIt("af");
console.log(x.getName());//says "undefined" - how to call it?

var y = obj.sayIt("xy");
console.log(y.sayHello());//says "undefined" - how to call it?
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QQwsk/1/)

Comment: You are returning nothing from obj methods

Comment: in Obj.nameIt, i am passing a name, and setting to this.name, later i calling the method.. what is wrong here?

Comment: `var x = obj.nameIt("af")` here x is undefined because nameIt method returns nothing. See e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/PKhqF/  If you don't want to return something, then don't use variable, get directly obj property as: `obj.name`

Comment: yes, understand. as like your suggestion, how can i call "getName" - method from "this.sayHello"..?

Comment: You need to add `return this;` to your methods. Besides, in `sayHello` you won't get the name defined in `nameIt`, because you have just overwritten it in `sayIt`. You probably want a `name` variable local to `sayIt`, see http://jsfiddle.net/szuwe/1/

Comment: You are already calling it or i misunderstand what you are talking about

Comment: I understand the issue from both A.Wolff and pawel - demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not return anything.

```
obj.nameIt = function(name){

    this.name = name;

    this.getName = function(){
        return this.name;
    }
    return this;
}

obj.sayIt = function(name){

    this.name = name; var that = this;

    this.sayHello = function(){
        console.log("say" + this.name);
        return that.getName();
    }
    return this;
}
```